# Android Sqlite Duplicate Insertion

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a simple database table in android sqlite in which i have inserted some records initially but the problem is that each time when i run the application whole list of records is being inserted again. For Example,i have inserted 3 records in my table now when i run the application first time the database table is like :

Category 1- Topic 1- Data
 Category 2- Topic 2- Data
 Category 3- Topic 3- Data

Now if i run this application without inserting any new record, the database table will look like:
 Category 1- Topic 1- Data
 Category 2- Topic 2- Data
 Category 3- Topic 3- Data
 Category 1- Topic 1- Data
 Category 2- Topic 2- Data
 Category 3- Topic 3- Data

How should i prevent this? Please help, its really urgent.

Here is my code:

DataColumns.java:

```
public class DataColumns {


 String KEY_CATEGORY = "_category";
String KEY_TOPIC  = "_topic";
  String KEY_DATA= "_datatoshow";


   public DataColumns() {}
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    public DataColumns(String _CAT, String _TOPIC, String _DATA)
    {
        this.KEY_CATEGORY = _CAT;
        this.KEY_TOPIC= _TOPIC;
        this.KEY_DATA = _DATA;
    }

    public DataColumns(String topic, String data)
    {

        this.KEY_TOPIC = topic;
        this.KEY_DATA = data;
    }


    public String getCATEGORY()
    {
        return this.KEY_CATEGORY;
    }

    public void setCATEGORY(String _cat)
    {
        this.KEY_CATEGORY = _cat;
    }

    public String getTOPIC()
    {
        return this.KEY_TOPIC;
    }

    public void setTOPIC(String topic)
    {
        this.KEY_TOPIC = topic;
    }

    public String getDATA()
    {
        return this.KEY_DATA;
    }

    public void setDATA(String data)
    {
        this.KEY_TOPIC = data;
    }

}
```

DataBaseHandler.java:

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "_CATEGORY";
    public static final String KEY_TOPIC = "_TOPIC";
    public static final String KEY_DATA = "_DATA";

     public static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "DB_TABLE";


        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WMCPROJECT.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SQLITE_TABLE + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL,"  + KEY_DATA + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
            Log.d("db", "DATABASE CREATION"); 

        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             // Drop older table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);

            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);

        }


    void    addRecord( DataColumns col_values)
        {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(KEY_CATEGORY,col_values.getCATEGORY()); 
            values.put(KEY_TOPIC, col_values.getTOPIC());
            values.put(KEY_DATA, col_values.getDATA());
            // Inserting Row
            db.insertOrThrow(SQLITE_TABLE, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection


        }

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 DataBaseHandler dbhandler = new DataBaseHandler(this);

 dbhandler.addRecord(new DataColumns("CAT1","TOPIC 1","data to show");
 dbhandler.addRecord(new DataColumns("CAT2","TOPIC 2","data to show");
 dbhandler.addRecord(new DataColumns("CAT3","TOPIC 3","data to show");



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
void addRecord( DataColumns col_values)
        {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_CATEGORY,col_values.getCATEGORY()); 
        values.put(KEY_TOPIC, col_values.getTOPIC());
        values.put(KEY_DATA, col_values.getDATA());

                String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLENAME + " WHERE " + KEY_CATEGORY + " = " + "\""
                        + col_values.getCATEGORY() + "\"";

                Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
                if (c != null && c.getCount() != 0) {

                } else {
                    db.insert(TABLENAME, null, values);
                }
  }
```

Comment: It works in a way that when you insert records initially, now on each time you run the application, previous records are not being inserted again. But here, the problem is when i run application with some new records, now these new reocrds are not being inserted because it finds the "if condition" true.

Comment: Problem is solved by adding UNIQUE constraint to column KEY_DATA in create table command.

Answer (score 0):

Simply instead calling addRecord  in onCreate method you can call it in your DatabaseHandler class inside onCreate method like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SQLITE_TABLE + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL,"  + KEY_DATA + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
            Log.d("db", "DATABASE CREATION"); 
            addRecord(new DataColumns("CAT1","TOPIC 1","data to show");
            addRecord(new DataColumns("CAT2","TOPIC 2","data to show");
            addRecord(new DataColumns("CAT3","TOPIC 3","data to show");
        }
```

the onCreate method in SQLiteOpenHelper run only for first time database creating.

Comment: this is impossible because SQLiteOpenHelper only runs one time this method. you should remove addrecord lines in onCreate inside your activity.

Comment: My activity looks like :                                              public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
 DataBaseHandler dbhandler = new DataBaseHandler(this);
 }                                                                 But now database is not being created.

Comment: @user2011302 you should call getWritableDatabase method for physically create new database. so create  a method inside DataBaseHandler class like this ` public void open() throws SQLException {
  this.getWritableDatabase();
 }
`

Comment: Go to the Manage Application on your emulator or your device and Click the 'Clear Data' button then test your app again.

Comment: After clearing data app runs correct for the first time but when i run it agian, it again inserts whole list of records.

Comment: Problem is solved by adding UNIQUE constraint to column KEY_DATA in create table command.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your project and I noticed a problem. you have to use the db parameter inside onCreate of DataBaseHandler class to add for first time.
change your onCreate method in DataBaseHandler to this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SQLITE_TABLE
            + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_CATEGORY
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_DATA
            + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    Log.d("db", "DATABASE CREATION");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CATEGORY, "CAT1");
    cv.put(KEY_TOPIC, "TOPIC 1");
    cv.put(KEY_DATA, "data to show");
    db.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, cv);

    cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CATEGORY, "CAT2");
    cv.put(KEY_TOPIC, "TOPIC 2");
    cv.put(KEY_DATA, "data to show");
    db.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, cv);

    cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_CATEGORY, "CAT3");
    cv.put(KEY_TOPIC, "TOPIC 3");
    cv.put(KEY_DATA, "data to show");
    db.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, cv);

}
```

I have tested it and it worked correctly.